# Search in SQL WHERE value is SELECT, why now working?

Tags: sql

I want to SELECT all the rows where the value is the same as the selected value. I mean example:

| id | phone_num | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0123456789 | VALUE 1 |
| 2 | 0123456789 | VALUE 2 |
| 3 | 0987654321 | VALUE 3 |

So for example: I want to SELECT the number 1 ID phone number and check if the phone_number is uniqe or duplicated.

I tried with this query but not working:

```
SELECT * 
FROM customers a, (SELECT b.phone_num as phone_search
                   FROM customers b
                   WHERE b.id = "1") AS total  
WHERE phone_num LIKE "%"|| total.phone_search ||"%"
```

Comment: do you want to search, or do you want to check for duplicates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a subquery in the `WHERE` clause:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM customers
WHERE phone_num = (SELECT phone_num FROM customers WHERE id = 1);
```

More generally, if you just want to flag any numbers which are duplicate, use an aggregation query:

```sql
SELECT phone_num
FROM customers
GROUP BY phone_num
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Comment: Thank you, sorry for late answer. Your query is working fine but one side note. I had a LIKE %% operator in my query but in your query there is not. Thank you!

Comment: Is it okay to use this way?
SELECT *
FROM customers
WHERE phone_num LIKE
 (SELECT CONCAT('%',phone_num,'%') 
 FROM customers WHERE id = 1)

Comment: Yes that might work depending on what you want to do.